# Need help understanding why i get attribute error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just beginning to learn python from python crash course by Eric Matthes and  it keeps telling me that I have an attribute error

```
motor_bikes = 'harley', 'Fz07', 'Crouch rocket'

last_owned = motor_bikes.pop()

print(last_owned)
```

Suppose to pop the last index from the list so I can use it in new variable `lasted_owned`

Answer (score 5):

You are creating a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#tuple), not a [list](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#list). Tuples are immuteable, they have no `.pop()`. The error literally tells you as much:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'pop'
> ```

```
motor_bikes = ['harley', 'Fz07', 'Crouch rocket']  # this is a muteable list

last_owned = motor_bikes.pop()  # it has a pop method

print(last_owned)
```

works:

```
Crouch rocket
```

You create tuples by:

```
t1 = 1,3,4
t2 = 1,
t3 = (1,2,3,)

print(t1,t2,t3)  # (1, 3, 4), (1,), (1, 2, 3)  -all tuples
```